# Move divs in pairs on window resize

Tags: css

This should be simple for you CSS gurus, but I really can't get this going. There are 4 boxes, example code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="firstPair">
        <div style="width: 200px; float: left"></div>
        <div style="width: 200px; float: left"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="secondPair">
        <div style="width: 200px; float: left"></div>
        <div style="width: 200px; float: left"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the window width is less than 800 only the rightmost div is moved, leaving them with 3 on top, and 1 on the next row.

I want the second two to go down the page as a pair. 2 on top, 2 on bottom, even if there is space for 3 next to eachother.

Comment: Why not give your firstPair/secondPair divs a width of 400px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set style for firstPair and secondPair elements

```css
div[id$="Pair"] {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="firstPair">
        <div style="width: 200px; float: left">s</div>
        <div style="width: 200px; float: left">d</div>
    </div>
    <div id="secondPair">
        <div style="width: 200px; float: left">f</div>
        <div style="width: 200px; float: left">g</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And one more solution with shorten html, but some more use css

```css
div[id$="Pair"] {
  display: inline-block;
}

[id$="Pair"] > div {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background: lightgreen;
}
#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="firstPair">
        <div>s</div>
        <div>d</div>
    </div>
    <div id="secondPair">
        <div>f</div>
        <div>g</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
div[id$="Pair"] {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

[id$="Pair"] > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 2px 0;
  background: lightgreen;
}
#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="firstPair">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="secondPair">
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a whole lot. This works, however I used to center the divs with "margin: 0 auto;" and that doesn't seem to work anymore.

Can you please help me center each of them evenly even if they are in pairs like this?

Comment: I've adapted second snippet. have a look

Comment: Thanks, I kind of got there too, but I'm looking to have them evenly centered as if they aren't in separate containers. Something like this http://sketchtoy.com/67873841 . Sorry to waste your time with simple stuff by the way, CSS is my kryptonite sadly.

Comment: I don't know is it what you asked - look at 3rd snippet

Answer (score 1):

It is about [BFC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context).

You might also float the containers :

```css
#wrapper> div {
  float:left;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="firstPair">
        <div style="width: 200px; float: left">1</div>
        <div style="width: 200px; float: left">2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="secondPair">
        <div style="width: 200px; float: left">3</div>
        <div style="width: 200px; float: left">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. I tend to work in a fully responsive environment, so this will position them and be fully responsive on mobile. I also isolated the css, the inline colors are just for demo.

```css
<style>
div#firstPair {
 width: 100%;
 max-width:400px;
 float: left;
}
div#firstPair div{
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}
div#secondPair {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 400px;
 float: left;
}
div#secondPair div{
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="firstPair">
        <div style="background-color: blue;">first_1</div>
        <div style="background-color: green;">first_2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="secondPair">
        <div style="background-color: red;">second_1</div>
        <div style="background-color: orange;">second_2</div>
    </div>
 <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```